# Fill Temp table with CTE Resut?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have 2 CTE That both of them select for me some records . one them is X and the other one is Y . in other hand i have 2 temp table with same name as CTE. i want fill these temp table with CTE Result . and in the end i want show these temp table in one result .
my problem is that i just can use CTE data source only one time here
 is my code

```
        use fidilio
;WITH Fidili_CTE1X ( FirstName,LastName,SubscribedDate, RegisteredDate, pers)
AS
(
SELECT 
FirstName,LastName,SubscribedDate, RegisteredDate,dbo.GetShDate(RegisteredDate) as pers
FROM ClubProfile CP 
WHERE CP.CardNumber IS NOT NULL
AND IsExpired =0
)

SELECT LastName,pers FROM Fidili_CTE1X
  CREATE TABLE #TEMPX
 (
      Lastname nvarchar(max) ,pers varchar(10)
 )
 Insert into #TEMPX 
 select * from Fidili_CTE1X
 ;WITH FIDILIO_CTE2Y(irstName,LastName,SubscribedDate, RegisteredDate,PERS)
 AS
 (
   SELECT 
FirstName,LastName,SubscribedDate, RegisteredDate,dbo.GetShDate(RegisteredDate) as pers
FROM ClubProfile CP 
WHERE CP.CardNumber IS NOT NULL
)


SELECT  LASTNAME,PERS FROM FIDILIO_CTE2Y

CREATE TABLE #TEMPY
(
Lastname nvarchar(max) ,pers varchar(10)
)
Insert into #TEMPY
select * from FIDILIO_CTE2Y
```

Comment: `;WITH cte1 AS (SELECT ...), cte2 AS (SELECT ...) SELECT col1,col2 INTO #x FROM (SELECT col1,col2 FROM cte1 UNION ALL SELECT col1,col2 FROM cte2) AS x;`

Comment: if you see my code , i used this method but the problem is that it does not recognize my cte datasource

Comment: Would  you please correct my code ?

Comment: CTE's by nature can only be used once, and only directly after they are declared. In your code, you declare your CTE fideli_cte1x, then you create a temp table, and THEN you try to access it. Create your temp table first, then declare your CTE, and immediately use it to insert. If you want to use the same CTE twice, you either need to declare it twice, or persist the contents of the CTE in something like a temp table or table variable so you can access them repeatedly.

Comment: I can't correct your code because I can't really tell what you want. The only differences between the queries is that one filters on IsExpired = 0. Do you want all the non-expired users to appear in the query results twice? Also what is the point of having the registered date (never mind the registered date formatted by an inefficient, scalar user-defined function) in the CTE, since you never actually use those columns?

Comment: Better not to include your db name :) Fidilio man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
use fidilio
;WITH Fidili_CTE1X ( FirstName,LastName,SubscribedDate, RegisteredDate, pers)
AS
(
SELECT 
FirstName,LastName,SubscribedDate, RegisteredDate,dbo.GetShDate(RegisteredDate) as pers
FROM ClubProfile CP 
WHERE CP.CardNumber IS NOT NULL
AND IsExpired =0
)

SELECT LastName,pers  into #TEMPX  FROM Fidili_CTE1X

 ;WITH FIDILIO_CTE2Y(irstName,LastName,SubscribedDate, RegisteredDate,PERS)
 AS
 (
   SELECT 
FirstName,LastName,SubscribedDate, RegisteredDate,dbo.GetShDate(RegisteredDate) as pers
FROM ClubProfile CP 
WHERE CP.CardNumber IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT  LASTNAME,PERS  into #TEMPY FROM FIDILIO_CTE2Y

select * from FIDILIO_CTE2Y
```

Comment: Seriously? You just wanted someone to do your job for you? This code is crappy. STILL full of errors. It creates a temp table with some data in it, but then at the end, it SELECTs some OTHER data?

Answer (score 1):

I think your misunderstanding here is that CTEs do not SELECT any data. They create a table. You must interact with that table in the same way you would any other table.

However, your script is way more complicated than it needs to be. What would be the problem with this?

```
SELECT FirstName,LastName,SubscribedDate, RegisteredDate,dbo.GetShDate(RegisteredDate) as pers
INTO #TEMPY
FROM ClubProfile CP 
WHERE CP.CardNumber IS NOT NULL
```

That has the same result as your script, except I can't tell what columns you really want due to errors in the script.

Comment: Except, that answer is wrong. So is this one, really. It's impossible to tell what you really want in the output because you have not described it in English, OR in SQL. The answer above loads data into a temp table but outputs some different data from somewhere else. That can't possibly be what you want - you're creating temp data and NOT USING it?!